# taborderhint attribute on an input field inside an apex repeat

Tags: visualforce

**Background:**

I have a field set that I'm using for displaying a list of fields on a visualforce page and I'm using `apex:repeat` to iterate through the field set. For each of the fields I'm using `apex:inputField` referenced to an object in my controller. Following is an example of what I currently have:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" showHeader="true" collapsible="false">
    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.MyCustomObject__c.FieldSets.MyFieldSet}" var="fieldName">
        <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity[fieldName]}" styleClass="input200" />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

By default the tab order is alternating left-right (due to having 2 columns for the parent page block section).

**Question:**

What would be the easiest way to implement tab order vertically (all fields in the first column, then the second column)?

**Issues:**

There is a post from the official SF documentation on [Setting the tabIndex on Components Inside an Iteration](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_input_field_tabindex.htm). Since `tabIndex` is not supported anymore and it's replaced by `taborderhint`, I've tried setting that attribute instead to my input field which resulted with a compilation error:

> Attribute taborderhint is not supported for  when
>   this component is a direct or indirect child of `<apex:repeat>`

I have also thought of doing something with Javascript, though I can't assign a dynamic ID to the input field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing I've also tried was setting the standard html attribute `tabIndex`, although I overlooked the `html-` prefix when trying to assign pass-through html attributes  so it didn't work the first time of course. The solution was to use the attribute `html-tabIndex` in which you can write your eval formula of how to calculate your tab order. So this is how I got the vertical tab order working, please answer if you have a better approach!

```
<!-- Some other fields with tab index up to 13 -->

<apex:variable var="indexL" value="{!14}" /> <!-- starting tab order for the field set - left index (first column) -->
<apex:variable var="indexR" value="{!indexL + ($ObjectType.MyCustomObject__c.FieldSets.MyFieldSet.size / 2)}" /> <!-- starting number for the fields in the 2nd column, half of the size of the total fields in the field set -->
<apex:variable var="index" value="{!1}" /> <!-- current iteration index -->

<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" showHeader="true" collapsible="false">
    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.MyCustomObject__c.FieldSets.MyFieldSet}" var="fieldName">
        <!-- if it's an odd iteration number - use left index, even iteration number - right index -->
        <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity[fieldName]}" styleClass="input200" html-tabIndex="{!IF(MOD(index, 2) != 0, indexL, indexR)}">
            <!-- increase corresponding index -->
            <apex:variable var="indexL" value="{!indexL + 1}" rendered="{!MOD(index, 2) != 0}" />
            <apex:variable var="indexR" value="{!indexR + 1}" rendered="{!MOD(index, 2) == 0}" />
            <!-- increase current iteration index -->
            <apex:variable var="index" value="{!index + 1}" />
        </apex:inputField>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```