# Problem altering the format of fieldsets on visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, fieldsets

I have created a number of field sets (some quite large) as a means of easily developing a large visualforce page with many different types of data. This has really sped up development, however, the ordering when outputting the fieldsets is problematic. We are looking for two columns to shorten certain sections, however, rather than outputting each field in a vertical fashion and proceeding to the second column after reaching half of the list, it just alternates columns. Something similar to:

`1 2
 3 4`

When what we are actually looking for is:

`1 3
 2 4`

Does anyone know how to achieve this using visualforce? It seems like [this link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50914/taborderhint-attribute-on-an-input-field-inside-an-apex-repeat) was onto something similar, however, I want the actual fields to output in this order, not just assign the tab order. Any responses would be appreciated.

Comment: Just change your field set order to `1 3 2 4`.

Comment: This isn't very plausible for field sets that are very long. Plus, the order would be off if someone decided to add a few fields. Looking for a long term solution, not a quick fix.

Comment: That would be great to add as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this. I created a page block section (same as before) and set columns="2". I then nested two pageBlockSections with columns="1", and iterated halfway through the field set in the first pageBlockSection, and then started where I left off in the second section. The labels were a little different, but I was able to add styles to them on page load using jQuery.